# How to send and receive raw JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I need some help determining the direction to take this. I just need the program to send a fixed raw simple JSON formatted message to the server at a given IP and port then it needs to listen for a response on a given port and then write out the raw response to the console.

I found a few topics on doing JSON http requests but I don't think I am on the right track. This is the code I am trying to adapt.

```
public static void send_json()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://10.211.55.5:7752");
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Method = "POST";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write("{\"request\": \"get_menu\", \"checksum\": \"\", \"table_state\": {\"table_id\": \"1\", \"waiter_id\": \"1001\"}}");
    }

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string json = "";

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            json += reader.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.Write(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the posted code?

Comment: Off-topic, but you can use `read.ReadToEnd()` instead of appending to a string.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want to look up Sockets. They're the underlying technology to HTTP requests, which have a lot more overhead. So if you *just* want to send and receive JSON, without headers or anything (again, what it sounds like you want to do), try looking into those.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, yes thats exactly what I am trying to do. I will research sockets and post back when I have a better understanding. Thanks everyone!

To explain the objective, I have a server that listen on a certain port for JSON formatted requests. The request in particular is a request to view a restaurant menu. So I send the menu request JSON message, the server receives it then sends the raw JSON formatted menu back to me... then I display that in the raw. Should be pretty straight forward... just not for me haha.

Comment: So you want a REST service? Is it a WCF Service with WebHttpBinding?

Comment: What **protocol** does your server speak? You'll need to make your request in terms of that protocol. If your server is a web server that speaks HTTP, a `WebRequest` is what you want. If it's using some other protocol, you'll likely need to go a different route, using a framework or library that supports that protocol or possibly even dropping down to sockets and speaking directly to the server.

Comment: Yea there is no specific protocol for this, everything is proprietary. I know it isn't http but thats the only way I could find to send JSON at all. It does look like sockets are the way to go as I am sending and receiving raw data.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ended up working! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!

```
private void pos_test_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 7777);

        string get_menu_request = "{\"request\": \"get_menu\"}";
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(get_menu_request);
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string _returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

        test_log_box.AppendText("\r\n\r\nPOS Connection Test: " + "\r\n" + _returndata);
    }
```